The Dirichlet hyperbola method and the non vanishing of $L(1,\chi)$
In several texts, they show a proof of the non-vanishing of  $L(1, \chi)$, where $\chi \neq \chi_0 $ is a real character using Dirichlet's hyperbola method. For example, in Apostol’s book (p. 142, Theorem 6.20) or in the book by Iwaniec and Kowalski. There, they define the function
$$ A(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} \chi(d) $$
and estimate  $B(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{A(n)}{\sqrt{n}} $, which gives $ B(x) = 2 \sqrt{x} L(1, \chi) + O(1) $, and the result follows because $B(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to\infty$.
I understand that the reason for using the hyperbola method here is because we’re dealing with partial sums of a convolution. But I wonder what is the underlying idea of the proof. Is there a way to motivate the study of these functions? And who was the first mathematician to present this proof?

Here are some underlying facts related to the proof (you can decide whether it rises to the level of an idea of the proof):
Since $A=\chi*1$, the Dirichlet series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty A(n)n^{-s}$ is equal to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n)n^{-s} \cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1n^{-s} = L(s,\chi)\zeta(s).$$ This in turn is equal to the Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_K(s)$ for the quadratic field $K=Q(\sqrt d)$ where $d$ is the conductor of $\chi$, which is entire other than a simple pole at $s=1$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{A(n)}{\sqrt n}n^{-s} = \zeta_K(s+\frac12)$, Perron's formula says that we expect $\sum_{n\le x} \frac{A(n)}{\sqrt n}$ to be asymptotic to the residue of $\zeta_K(s+\frac12) \frac{x^s}s$ at $s=\frac12$ (its rightmost pole), which is precisely $2\sqrt x \cdot L(\chi,\frac12)$.
As for the source of the argument, Montgomery and Vaughan (in Section 4.4 of their Multiplicative Number Theory I) attribute the approach in the OP to Landau in 1906.
